# Duplicate html form field rows with button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to duplicate this entire form field when I click on the "Add Row" button. For some reason when I reload the page, the second row I'm trying to duplicate appears and the button click to "Add row" that fires up the function doesn't work either. I'm obviously doing something wrong here?

```js
var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
  counter++;
  var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.id = '';
  newFields.style.display = 'row';
  var newField = newFields.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
      newField[i].name = theName + counter;
  }
  var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
}
window.onload = moreFields;
```

```html
<div class="row" id="readroot">

  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="fullname[]" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-sm">
      <select name="gnation[]" id="national" class="mdb-select person-title grey-text" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected> Nationality </option>
        <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
        <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
        <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
        <option value="american">American</option>
        <option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
        <option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
        <!-- a lot more -->
        <option value="zambian">Zambian</option>
        <option value="zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
      </select>
      <label for="national"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="contact[]" placeholder="Contact" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="gemail[]" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="gorganisation[]" placeholder="Organisation" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm">
      <a onclick="this.moreFields();" id="moreFields" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add Row</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="writeroot"></div>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger waves-effect waves-light pull-right" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">
```

Answer (score 0):

There were couple of issue;

add row has id="morefields"; on duplicating we will have two elements with same id; this is not good;

so i add morefields to class; Also on adding new row, script doesnt know that new html element has been created with class "morefields";

so i placed the eventlistener inside a function and I am invoking it on two occasions

1) on page load

2) on click of add row (with a small timeout).

thus when add row, new row is created and the 'add row' anchor is binded with correct event listener

```js
var counter = 0;

//document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;

window.onload = loadEventListener();

function loadEventListener() {
  let addRowAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName('moreFields');

  for(i=0;i<addRowAnchorTags.length; i++) {
      addRowAnchorTags[i].onclick = moreFields;
  }
}

function moreFields() {
  counter++;
  var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.id = '';
  newFields.style.display = 'row';
  var newField = newFields.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
      newField[i].name = theName + counter;
  }
  var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
  setTimeout(function() {loadEventListener();})
}
//window.onload = moreFields;
```

```html
<div class="row" id="readroot">

  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="fullname[]" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-sm">
      <select name="gnation[]" id="national" class="mdb-select person-title grey-text" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected> Nationality </option>
        <option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
        <option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
        <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
        <option value="american">American</option>
        <option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
        <option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
        <!-- a lot more -->
        <option value="zambian">Zambian</option>
        <option value="zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
      </select>
      <label for="national"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="contact[]" placeholder="Contact" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="gemail[]" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm new_row">
      <input type="text" name="gorganisation[]" placeholder="Organisation" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="md-form form-sm">
      <a id="moreFields" class=" moreFields btn btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add Row</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="writeroot"></div>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger waves-effect waves-light pull-right" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">
```